# Oracle ASM Restriping Cost

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I was doing research on the differences between oracle asm and filesystem and the advantages of asm. I found one of the advantages of ASM was 'striping'. Data is kept by dividing it into different disks within a diskgroup, and thus faster results are obtained by running the disks in parallel.

So, in this method, what is the cost of dividing the data into different disks and combining them again while processing the data? Is this cost not mentioned in any source because its place in the equation is very low?

I searched oracle documents but couldn't find anything about restriping cost.

Comment: this question is better asked at https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is basically a software RAID scenario. It is transparent to the database instance and the SQL engine, and performance is entirely dependent on the underlying hardware characteristics, the general load on the storage system (SAN, NAS, local disk array, etc.), the degree of striping taking place, the quantity of data involved, whether or not any of the data is cached in memory (buffer cache or storage system cache) at any given time, etc. Cost is not addressed directly in the documentation any more than any other storage architecture because the answer will always be "it depends...".